# I'm trying to use Firebase using my Apple account but I cannot find Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles

Tags: ios, xcode

Do I need to complete the purchase of my Developer account in order to use these features ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some features like Push Notification, Device Testing, etc require you do have the $99 developer account.